# Distributing fruits to 3 people.

Tags: combinatorics

We have 8 (identical) apples, 6 oranges, and 7 pears, to distribute among 3 people

A) without restriction

B) where each person gets at least 1 pear.

For A, I had tried to use "stars and bars" and got $10\choose 2$$ 9\choose 2$$8\choose 2$.

Then for B, I calculated how many ways to distribute them where each person gets exactly 0 pears, and then subtracted that from the total, getting $10 \choose 2$ [$9\choose 2$$-1$]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempt of A) is indeed correct. The second question can easily be answered by first giving everyone a pear and then dividing the ones left over. Do you think you can answer it now?

Comment: Wouldn't it just be changing the pears to $6\choose 2$ instead? That definitely makes sense. Why is what I did wrong?

Comment: Changing your distribution of pears to ${6 \choose 2}$ is correct. How did you try to substract the cases where someone has 0 pears?

Comment: I figured that'd be the compliment of having "at least 1". So I thought I'd subtract the compliment if that event from the total possible outcomes.

Comment: Ahh I understand. Thank you, friend!

Answer (score 2):

A looks good

For B, just give everyone 1 pear first. So instead of 7 pears, there are now only 4 pairs. Then do it the same way you did A.